# ParseQuery NullPointer Exception Paradox

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, nullpointerexception

This is a follow-up to my previous question: [Parse RecyclerView Image Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796122/parse-recyclerview-image-query)

I am now having a paradoxical nullpointer exception. I am attempting to extract a list from an inner method, in the way outlined below.

```
public List<ParseObject> objectList;

public List<String> getData(String filter){

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Images");
    query.whereEqualTo("category", filter);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        public void done(List<ParseObject> downloads, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                objectList=downloads;
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    int size = objectList.size();

    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        ParseFile file = (ParseFile) objectList.get(i).get("Image");
        urlList.add(file.getUrl());
    }

    return urlList;

}
```

How do I solve this? What ways exist which are better than what I am using?

EDIT:

Here is what it's doing. At present there are no exceptions, but the recyclerview is not displaying anything.

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_events, container, false);
    setList("sport", rootView);
    return rootView;
}

public void set() {

}

public void setList(String filter, View view){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getData(filter));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

EDIT 2: More updated code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_events, container, false);
    setList("sport", rootView);
    return rootView;
}

public void set() {

}

public void setList(String filter, View view){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getData(filter));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}


private List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();



public List<ParseObject> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
public int size;

public List<String> getData(String filter){


    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Images");
    query.whereEqualTo("category", filter);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        public void done(List<ParseObject> downloads, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Downloads retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                objectList.addAll(downloads);
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            size = objectList.size();
        }
    });



    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        ParseFile file = (ParseFile) objectList.get(i).get("Image");
        urlList.add(file.getUrl());
    }

    return urlList;

}
```

EDIT 3: Updated, and I have added my adapter code.

```
    View rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_events, container, false);
    new GetUrlListTask(this).execute("sport");
    return rootView;
}

public void set() {

}



private List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();



public List<ParseObject> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
public int size;

public List<String> getData(String filter){


    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Images");
    query.whereEqualTo("category", filter);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        public void done(List<ParseObject> downloads, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Downloads retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                objectList.addAll(downloads);
            } else {

            }

            size = objectList.size();
        }
    });



    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        ParseFile file = (ParseFile) objectList.get(i).get("Image");
        urlList.add(file.getUrl());
    }

    return urlList;

}

private class GetUrlListTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,List<String>>
{
    private WeakReference<Fragment> weakRef;

    public GetUrlListTask(Fragment frag){
        weakRef = new WeakReference< Fragment >(frag);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... filters) {
        return getData(filters[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> urlList) {
        Fragment frag = weakRef.get();
        if (frag != null){
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv);
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(urlList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

And My adapter:

```
   List<String> urls;
ViewGroup parent;

public MyAdapter(List<String> urls){
    this.urls=urls;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_entry, parent);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    this.parent=parent;
    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Picasso.with(parent.getContext())
            .load(urls.get(position))
            .into(holder.photo);
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), urls.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return urls.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView photo;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        photo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listImage);

    }
}
```

Comment: Lack of knowledge, not paradox... http://ideone.com/PPHi95

Comment: What may seem impossible to an ant may be easy for an elephant. That's a compliment.

Answer (score 1):

So I am assuming that what you want to do is once you get the urlList, you want to update some view. If that's the case then I think what you want to do it run that whole method in a background task rather than just the query like so:

First change your getData() method:

```
public List<String> getData(String filter){

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Images");
    query.whereEqualTo("category", filter);

    objectList = query.find(); //I think you have to surround this by a try catch or have the method throw an exception

    int size = objectList.size();
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        ParseFile file = (ParseFile) objectList.get(i).get("Image");
        urlList.add(file.getUrl());
   }

    return urlList;
}
```

Note that since you are doing a network call, the above method now HAS to run from a background thread.

Then you can use something like an AsyncTask to update a view:

```
private class GetUrlListTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,List<String>>
{
    private WeakReference<Fragment> weakRef;

    public PhotoTagsFetchTask(Fragment frag){
        weakRef = new WeakReference< Fragment >(frag);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... filters) {
        return getData(filters[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> urlList) {
        Fragment frag = weakRef.get();
        if (frag != null){
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(urlList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the use of weak reference above is to avoid context leaks (basically avoids unnecessary memory leaks).

You could also do this:

```
public void getData(String filter){

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Images");
query.whereEqualTo("category", filter);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

    public void done(List<ParseObject> downloads, com.parse.ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            objectList=downloads;
            int size = objectList.size();

            for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
              ParseFile file = (ParseFile) objectList.get(i).get("Image");
              urlList.add(file.getUrl());
            }

            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(urlList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});



}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85238/discussion-between-teslak20-and-sree).

Comment: @TeslaK20 Sorry, that should be protected List<String> doInBackground(String... filters)

Comment: I updated my code. At present the recyclerview displays nothing.

Comment: Did you try both ways? If you did, I suggest you debug your code. Check to make sure you are getting objects back from parse. I don't want to write out everything for you (even though thats basically what I did for you lol).

Comment: I realized I had not fully implemented your code, so I did that and now I get:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: It is not traced to any of my code. All the links are gray.

Answer (score 0):

Change `objectList=downloads` to `objectList.addAll(downloads)` and add `objectList = new ArrayList<>()` in the first line.

Also move the section starting from`objectList.size()` inside the `done` method of query callback

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.addAll(java.util.Collection)' on a null object reference.

Comment: I don't think this would help because objectList will always be size = 0 because the query will not be done

Comment: @Sree actually you're wrong. Cause that is the query.findInBackround() as not query execution?

Comment: mmm... i dunno about that. This code is run on the UI thread and the findInBackground will start a background thread. so int size = objectList.size(); will always be 0 because it won't wait for that background thread to finish

Comment: In that aspect you're right. But findInBackground() named in this way as it runs in background

Comment: @OlegOsipenko yep, precisely. but the method doesn't wait for it to finish running in the background

Comment: I have updated my code. At present there is no NPE, but the recyclerview displays nothing.

Comment: This is still not working. I have implemented sree's method and the debug windows does not trace my exception to my code. The problem might be with the adapter. Please.

Comment: Actually, you're using SO in a wrong way. There is one question for one technical problem and then, after solving this problem if you stuck on next problem you creates another question. And if you change your code you need to update code in question with relevant version

As your question states NPE problem I helped you to eliminate NPE, and you had to accept my answer. And then, as you're facing new problem create another question. Or try to find the answer for previously asked question

Comment: I meant to post this long ago, at the end of August, but eventually the problem was that I didn't put in the argument "false" into a function in a different section of the code. You both helped me a lot, thank you very much.